# Command line: Extract substring from output

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Say I run the command SayStuff

```
$ SayStuff
```

and the output is

```
Watermelons and cucumbers
```

Now. Say I want to extract the substring `cucumbers` from the output and pipe it into something.
The way I would go about this programmatically would be to split the output into an array by the delimiter *Space* and reference it by `ArrayName[2]`. I am fairly new to shell scripts and have only succeeded in digging up semi-cryptic `cut` examples, none of which made sense.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
$ echo "Watermelons and cucumbers" | cut -d ' ' -f 3
cucumbers
```

The `-d ' '` tells `cut` to split on spaces. `-f 3` selects the third column.

You can also use `awk`, which does the splitting based on space already and makes the columns available as `$1`, `$2`, …

```
$ echo "Watermelons and cucumbers" | awk '{ print $3 }'
cucumbers
```

Comment: Note that `cut` will not handle a variable number of spaces, while `awk` do.

Answer (score 20):

I would probably use one of the options already given by @slhck but here are a few more ways of doing this:

1. Using arrays, as you would in any other language:

   ```
    $ foo=( $(SayStuff) ) 
    $ echo ${foo[2]}
    cucumbers
   ```

   The `var=()` declares an array, `$(command)` saves the output of the command. So, `foo=( $(SayStuff) )`  stores the output of `SayStuff` into the array `foo` and yuou then `echo` its third element with `${foo[2]}`.
2. `sed`

   ```
    $ SayStuff | sed 's/.* \(.*\)/\1/'
    cucumbers
   ```

   The `sed` command will substitute (`s///`) everything with the last word. The regex matches anything up to a space (`.*` ) which will match everything up to the last space and then captures the last word `(\(.*\)`. Since the word has been captures, we can refer to it as `\1`.

   A simpler version:

   ```
    $ SayStuff | sed 's/.* //'
    cucumbers
   ```
3. bash

   ```
    $ foo=$(SayStuff); echo ${foo##* } 
    cucumbers
   ```

   This uses bash's string manipulation abilities, see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for more details.
4. More bash

   ```
    $ SayStuff | while read a b c; do echo $c; done
    cucumbers
   ```
5. Perl, where of course, there are many ways to do this:

   ```
    $ SayStuff | perl -lane 'print $F[$#F]'
    cucumber
   ```

   The `-a` makes `perl` behave like `awk`, splitting lines at whitespace and saving into the array `@F`. We then print the last element of `@F` (`$#F` is the number of elements in `@F`). The `-l` tells perl to add a newline to each `print` statement, the `-n` that it should process STDIN line by line and `-e` that it should run the script given at the command line.

   ```
    $ SayStuff | perl -pe 's/.* //'
    cucumber
   ```

   The options were explained above, we are just deleting everything till the last space and printing (`-p`).

   ```
    $ perl -le 'print $ARGV[$#ARGV]' $(SayStuff)
    cucumbers
   ```

   Here we are passing `Watermelons and cucumbers` as arguments, which perl will save in the `@ARG` array and so, we print the last element of `@ARG`.
6. trickery. This one uses `sed` to convert spaces to newlines and then `tail` to print only the last line.

   ```
    $ SayStuff | sed 's/ /\n/g' | tail -n 1
    cucumbers
   ```
7. grep and regular expressions, using `-o` which prints only the matched string.

   ```
    $ SayStuff | grep -Po '\w+$' 
    cucumbers
   ```
8. cheating

   ```
    $ SayStuff | grep -o cucumbers
    cucumbers
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some more explanation:

```
Usage: cut OPTION... [FILE]...

Print selected parts of lines from each FILE to standard output.

   -d, --delimiter=DELIM
          use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter

   -f, --fields=LIST
          select only these fields;  also print any line that contains  no
          delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified
```

So if you need the 3rd field and it is delimited by spaces ' ' then it is

```
$ echo "Watermelons and cucumbers" | cut -d ' ' -f 3  
cucumbers
```

If you want the **LAST** field you probably should use **awk**.
In this case it becomes:

> $ echo "Watermelons and cucumbers" | awk '{ print $NF }'
>   cucumbers

In `awk` NF is the number of fields in the line so `$NF` means the last field in the line.

Comment: basically the same question is here but more generalized: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162385/how-to-split-a-string-in-shell-and-get-the-last-field

Yes you can use other ways but awk is the shortest